# in_array() how to check two values PHP WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am checking two roles of user but it's not working. I am checking that in `in_array()` but when I pass only one value then it's working but when I pass two values it's not working.

PHP with two values of user role, it's not working. What is wrong in the code?

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'editor','author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        remove_menu_page('edit.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: `in_array( 'editor', (array) $user->roles ) || in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles )`

Comment: [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array) only takes one value to search for

Answer (score 0):

**1st approach.**

```
if(in_array('foo',$arg) && in_array('bar',$arg)){
    //both of them are in $arg
}
```

**2nd approach**

use of array_intersect()
e.g:

```
$arrayData = array(...);

$target = array('foo', 'bar');

if(count(array_intersect($arrayData, $target)) == count($target)){
    // all of $target is in $arrayData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_intersect() function the targets with the haystack and make sure the intersection is precisely equal to the targets:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$haystack = (array) $user->roles;

$target = array('editor', 'author');

if(count(array_intersect($haystack, $target)) == count($target)){
    // all of $target is in $haystack
}
```